# What is the best way to make multiple database calls using Python?

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy, azure-functions

Assume that I have to do some validation which includes many DB calls, so I created multiple functions for each task. And I have given the two options with sample code please let me know the best option.

**Option A:**

```
def do_big_task():
    get_data_from_function_1(a, b)
    # do some analysis
    get_data_from_function_2(c, d)
    # do some more analysis
    update_some_data_in_table_a(e, f, g)
    # completed the task
    return "Validation Passed"
```

This is how sample functions (from Option-A) looks like:

```
def get_data_from_function_1(a, b):
    try:
        with get_connection_obj() as cursor:
            return cursor.execute('Some SQL statement').fetchall()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        raise Exception(e)
```

**NOTE:** Remaining functions also looks like same.

**Option B:**

```
def do_big_task():
    try:
        with get_connection_obj() as cursor():
            get_data_from_function_1(cursor, a, b)
            # do some analysis
            get_data_from_function_2(cursor, c, d)
            # do some more analysis
            update_some_data_in_table_a(cursor, e, f, g)
            # completed the task
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        raise Exception(e)
    return "Validation Passed"
```

This is how sample functions (from Option-B) looks like:

```
def get_data_from_function_1(cursor, a, b):
    try:
        return cursor.execute('Some SQL statement').fetchall()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        raise Exception(e)
```

**NOTE:** Remaining functions also looks like same.

QUESTION: What is the recommended way to complete that validation ?

Comment: Can you be more specific about the nature of your db calls? Do you mean many clients making calls, asynchronous calls etc? In any case it might be better from a performance point of view to use connection pooling and an async db driver such as asyncpg. Option B seems to want to keep the same connection open for at least one request but serving various calls in the big task. It also seems that on completion of your big task you are updating a table which at least in my mind seems like you want an atomic transaction.

Comment: https://calpaterson.com/async-python-is-not-faster.html

Comment: @Markonick Just for clarity, I am not making any asynchronous calls, all functions has to be executed in synchronous way, so that I have to use the output of one function into some other function.